# Can not change currentPage property in UIPageControl

Tags: swift, uipagecontrol

```
private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    appearance.currentPage = 2
}
```

I'm trying to change first position of UIPageControl in my app but I can't get appropriate result with this code.

Comment: currentPage can be accessed as pageControl.currentPage = something where pageControl is the UIPageControl outlet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the `currentPage` through the appearance proxy which obviously does not and should not work.

Set the property in the same way to your page control property/variable for it to work.

To know which selectors are supposed to work with the appearance proxy, check the class' Objective-C header file and look for `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` attribute

[image: UIPageControl.h]